# hashset, dictionary, arraylist: can`t see the forest for the trees

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, arraylist, hashset

About:
My mathematical program will have a giant **collection** of items to **iterate** through. It will mainly consist of an **item** and a **pointer** to an other item ((int)item,(int) pointer), resembling a key value pair.
However, each item on his own will have several other **attributes** like this:

(item, pointer),(attribute, attribute, attribute, ...)

Items, pointers and attributes will be added frequently.

Searching this site and others has made me only more clueless about what collection to use for the program.

At this moment a **Dictionary** solution found on vcskicks.com seems to work best:

```
Dictionary<Dictionary<int,int>,Dictionary<int,int> nestedDictionary = 
    new Dictionary<Dictionary<int,int>,Dictionary<int,int> nestedDictionary();
```

or in plain language:

```
Dictionary<Dictionary<item, pointer>, 
           Dictionary<attribute,attribute, ...> nestedDictionary =      
    Dictionary<Dictionary<item, pointer>, 
               Dictionary<attribute,attribute, ...>();
```

Please note that the number of attributes are not predefined, it varies in length. Also at this moment Im reluctant to use objects because of the performance overhead.

**Hashsets** don`t seem to fit in because duplicate items will exist, however they will have different attributes. **Or** can a hashset have duplicate items but just not duplicate hashkeys? There seem to be some confusion.

According to some the following hashset will not compute:

```
11011, 0001
11011, 0011
```

According to others it will, because it will have a different hashkey. It leaves me puzzled.

**My question:**

At risk of being to vague: What is the best collection type to use? Ill be happy to add more to the story if necessary.

**Edits**:

**Giant means**: potentially millions of items. All items will have a pointer and attributes. 
**General use** will be **searching** for a particular item, retrieving the pointer, getting the item of the next pointer until there is no pointer left. At the same time all attributes for each item is collected. Adding will be done on a regular basis, removing only occasionally.
**Pointer**: the pointer is an index of the item it refers to. If you have 2 items, and the first is linked to the second then the first item will have the index of the second item as a pointer.
**Best** is defined as in memory usage and speed. At the end all found items will be compared to each other. 
**Example:**

```
[Item , pointer] [attribute, attribute, ...]
[11011,    1001] [ 1101,        1111 ]
[10001,    1000] [ 1110,        0101 ]
[11111,    0010] [ 1111,        1110 ]
[11011,    0001] [ 0010,        1010 ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a singly linked list

Comment: How big is 'giant'? What is the general use, lot of reading or a lot of adding/deleting? What kind of performance do you need?

Comment: I think you need to define "best". Are you thinking of memory consumption, speed, easy of coding, something else?

Comment: Also if you need a dictionary in a dictionary, think about using a class for maintaining the inner dictionary.

Comment: If you don't want to use objects because of the performance overhead, then you chose the wrong language. That's exactly what you're doing with each item you add in the dictionary, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: you are right. My idea too. At this moment however c# is the closest I get for programming. It is very accessible for programming a graphical user interface and to reap results. If the program gets some good results I will invest more time to finetune the performance.

Comment: If it's meant to iterate, why use a dictionary? You could also use a List<T,U>.

Comment: I read a dictionary would be "extremely useful" to handle index keys. Since the main data is about key value pairs I thought it might good to use a dictionary. However, my knowledge about programming is fairly minimal. List<T,U> seems a good idea, but it makes uses of extra objects. That means creating an object for each item and attribute. Which I like to, if possible, avoid. I was more thinking on some kind of array(s) to store a key value pair and its attributes.

Comment: Do you need to "iterate" in any specific order? Do you need to do anything else beside iterate, for example search for a specific element and by what criteria? What does the "pointer" mean - it's obviously some kind of index, but what data structure is it intended to index? Does it _have_ to be an index or it can be just a reference? And finally, do you anticipate your "giant" dataset will fit into RAM?

Comment: If you want to stick with C#, there are a few things you're going to have to rethink. For example, using dictionaries to keep a pointer. When you make a Dictionary<A, B>, the objects in each item are essentially pointers. So you should probably think along the lines of using a list of objects (which you define), where these objects contain the necessary reference to the next item as well as any attributes.

Comment: "Sounds like a singly linked list – CodesInChaos" Seems like a good choice. However, the main array will have items linked to each other scattered all over it. Is  next and previous still maintainable or does it lose its edge to other lists?

Comment: Maybe you should use a database engine.

Comment: Look, if you have a list of 5 objects, then each object is kept in the list as a pointer (which you don't get access to). So you can keep a pointer to the 4th object in the 1st object if you like. You just have to set it in the object.

Comment: The pointer is an index of the item it refers to. If you have 2 items, and the first is linked to the second then the first item will have the index of the second item as a pointer.

Comment: You don't need to keep indices like that. I'll post an answer to illustrate.

Comment: I understand the mechanics of setting a pointer as a field or method in an object. However, this is not about pointers. It is about how to store an item, its pointer and its attributes in a collection. This collection will be used to search for a given item. Each found item will go through the pointers and collect each successive item and its attributes. At the end you will have a set of duplicate items with different attributes as shown in the example in the original post. My question is much simpler, what collection type would be best to use it.

Comment: at this moment Im inclined to use the Dictionary collection and eventually a linked list to store the result of all duplicate items with its attributes.

Comment: I look forward to your illustration Gigi, Thanks.

Comment: So, an item may have multiple pointers (ex. 11011)?

Comment: Why exactly do you need millions of items in memory like this? I believe you're adding yourself unnecessary work. You should be simplifying and abstracting, not making things more complex than they actually are... You worry about creating objects but you're fine with multiple nested collections? Doesn't sound like a good idea to me. Not mentioning you completely ignore every single OOP principle...

Comment: "Maybe you should use a database engine. – Alex Filipovici" Thanks for the input. Could you explain what a database engine could mean for me?

Comment: I'll do that. But first, could you answer my other question (multiple pointers for an item)?

Comment: "So, an item may have multiple pointers (ex. 11011)? – Alex Filipovician" An item has only one pointer (another item) but it can have multiple attributes.

Comment: Ok, then please edit the examples in your question, because they are confusing.

Comment: Walther: Millions items are bound to exist due to its process. However it is also bound to have duplicate items, but this is important to be able to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically it seems like you need to keep a collection of objects, each of which have the following properties:

- Reference to the logical *next* item
- Attributes

So an item would look something like this (just a quick example... not exactly best practice to keep everything public, but in your case you won't mind):

```
public struct MyItem
{
   public Dictionary<String, String> attributes;
   public MyItem next;
}
```

Then all you need is to keep a list:

```
List<MyItem> myList;
```

When you want to add something, it's easy:

```
MyItem item1 = new MyItem();
item1.attributes["name"] = "Joe";
item1.next = null; // this is the default behaviour... just illustrating here
myList.Add(item1);

MyItem item2 = new MyItem();
item2.attributes["name"] = "Mary";
item2.next = item1;
myList.Add(item2);
```

Then, when you want to traverse, just follow next.

```
MyItem item = myList[0];
while (item != NULL)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["name"]);
    item = item.next;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the question, `11011` has two pointers: `1001` and `0001`. I'm not sure if the poster of the question described very well the problem.

Comment: My understanding is that there's only one pointer... it's basically a singly linked list. This answer is mainly to illustrate a possible solution... we can refine this as necessary.

Comment: Hi Gigi, thanks for the answer. Ive been reading about structs. They seem to be the solution indeed. I think Ill go this way. Im still uncertain thou if hashsets could be of any help?

Comment: You may or may not want to use classes instead of structs... read up on the difference, but it won't affect you much if you just store data (like in this example). You probably don't want to use hash sets... they're the equivalent of the mathematical set, and used to keep distinct values (no duplicates), as well as allowing standard operations (e.g. union). From what I gathered, that's not what you need. Keep it simple.

Comment: Gigi, Thank you for the elaborate answer. It has aided me in seeing the problem more clear, thanks.

Comment: Btw, if each new item you add to the list is always the "next" of the last item in the list, it gets even simpler. I'm assuming here that you have several different sequences of objects related by the "next" pointer. You might even find that omitting "next" completely, and instead using many different lists, might suit you better. This depends on how your application is working exactly, and only you can determine that.

Comment: It is indeed so that the new item added is always the next of the last item in the list. Im not sure how you would put many different lists in practice to make it simpler.

Comment: If the new item is the next of the last, then you don't need a next pointer at all - it's implicit in the structure of the list. Instead of traversing with a while loop, use a for/foreach loop. Keep one list.

Comment: ok, then that is not always the case. Altough the new item is the next of the last it might itself refer to an item much earlier in the list. But I understand your input and up to a certain degree it would work. Thanks for thinking along.